# Deserialize different xml elements with same name into different C# classes

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have some XML which contains two `general` elements, each containing different information. For example:

```
<overview>
    <general> <!-- General 01 -->
        <datetime></datetime>
        <location></location>
    </general>
    <instance>
        <general> <!-- General 02 -->
            <instanceid></instanceid>
            <instancetype></instancetype>
        </general>
    </instance>
    <instance>
        ....
    </instance>
</overview>
```

After running this XML through [Xml2CSharp.com](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/), the information in both different `general` elements are combined into one class, for example:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="general")]
public class General {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="datetime")]
    public string Datetime { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="instanceid")]
    public string Instanceid { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="instancetype")]
    public string Instancetype { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to create two different classes for these `general` elements (since they each contain different information), and specify which should be used? For example:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="overview/general")]
public class OverviewGeneral {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="datetime")]
    public string Datetime { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot(ElementName="instance/general")]
public class InstanceGeneral {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="instanceid")]
    public string Instanceid { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="instancetype")]
    public string Instancetype { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closed to achieve your result, you need to assign proper class type to each property like

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "instance")]
public class Instance
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "general")]
    public InstanceGeneral General { get; set; }  //<= InstanceGeneral  Use Here
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "overview")]
public class Overview
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "general")]
    public OverviewGeneral General { get; set; }  //<= OverviewGeneral Use Here
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "instance")]
    public Instance Instance { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's so obvious when you see it... Thanks for your help (: